# get value of offset() and divide it by factor of windowheight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive the following problem:
on window resize im fireing some events and one of them is this:

```
var height = $(window).height()
var getfactor = $('.second').offset().left/height
var getleft = getfactor*height
```

with this im doing:

```
$('.second').css('left', getleft);
```

but on window resize its always on the same position, and no left is been manipulated.

Comment: Do you set the `position` property of `.second` in CSS?

Comment: absolute! that was the first i was looking for

Comment: and what about `left:0;` in css? i mean have you declared the default left pos? and try adding `+'px'` in `getleft+'px'`

Comment: in the css i have left:1000px, but it is not necessary which value it has before, because it overwrites it!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly you are essentially doing the following:

```
var getleft = ($('.second').offset().left / $(window).height()) * $(window).height();
```

Dividing by a number and then multiplying by that same number is going to cancel out any modification to the original left offset. You are essentially resetting the offset to its initial value every time the window is resized.